# Spring project in Eclipse - 404

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jsp, tomcat

I try to run the app on Tomcat but keep getting this error "The requested resource (/testapp/) is not available." - what might be wrong? I guess my XML setup is incorrect but not sure how to fix it.

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />

    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="HelloWorldPage" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

HelloWorldController.java - using Spring annotations.

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage");
        model.addObject("msg", "hello world");

        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error/exception at deploy time  ?

Comment: that is runtime error page you are getting, but I am asking is there any exception at deploy time

Comment: No JSP files in the tomcat directory which is odd

Comment: Check the tomcat startup logs.  I seems reasonable that your application failed to start; Tomcat started, but "testapp" failed to start

Comment: In localhost_access_log - the latest lines have "HTTP/1.1" 404 985"

Answer (score 2):

in your web.xml you map spring to *.htm but your controller is mapped to

```
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
```

you should map to

```
@RequestMapping("/welcome.htm")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not getting any exception on eclipse console, I think you are probably not hitting the right contextRoot of your project, mostly it's the exact name of your application, but sometimes it's different...

If you are not typing the app name wrongly try this.

Click on the project right mouse button click on properties.

Then search for Context.

you are going to find a section called ContextRoot

Use the string in that box to mount your Contextroot like this

localhost:8080/stringFound/

and hit enter in the browser.

Comment: Context root is the same as the project name.